# InvalidOperationException while trying to modify UI from another thread

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

I have a checkbox binded to a property that wraps timer.Enabled state.

MainForm:

```
chbTimer.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Checked", _inactividadController, "TimerEnabled")
            {
                DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged,
                ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged
            });
```

_inactividadController:

```
public bool TimerEnabled
    {
        get { return _timer.Enabled; }
        set
        {
            _timer.Enabled = value;
            InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TimerEnabled"));
        }
    }
```

_timer.Elapsed:

```
private void Test(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimerEnabled = false;
    }
```

Exception occurs here:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)  
                  handler(this, e); //<-- BOOM
    }
```

I fully understand whats going on here: Timer works on another thread and tries to update chbTimer which is on main thread and this is an illegal operation. But I got no idea on how to fix this issue.

Tried [this](http://www.claassen.net/geek/blog/2007/07/generic-asynchronous.html) approach but doesn't work since changes from the UI are not reflected on the binding (when the user checks the the checkbox the timer doesn't change state).

Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: Can you show your handler code as well?

Comment: You need to marshal the call onto the UI thread. Not sure how to do that in windows forms, other than use Control.Invoke, which won't really work here (without being hacky af).  Maybe create a SynchronizationContext on the UI thread (thus capturing it) then using that SC in your binding code?

Comment: @vendettamit sorry what? `PropertyChangedEventHandler` is right there. Not sure what handler you refer to.

Comment: @Will I don't know that class, I'm gonna read a bit about it right now

Comment: @Will i made it work using SynchronizationContext! thank you very much, posting answer right now

Comment: Good!  I'm not sure if that's the "official" way to do this, but it'll work fine for you.  Using a SynchronizationContext to abstract away thread management tasks is done in many parts of the framework, so at least it won't be too surprising to others working with the codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified the constructor of InactividadController so it receives a SynchronizationContext

on Form.cs

```
_inactividadController = new InactividadController(SynchronizationContext.Current);
```

and modified Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            _originalContext.Post(delegate
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Once you use the `SynchronizationContext`, there is absolutely no need of `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`.